# DocuSign for Salesforce Custom Button Email Message Length

Tags: docusignapi

I have an email message that is 317 characters in my custom button code, and when I press the button to test the code, I receive this error:
Illegal Request
You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request.
When I reduce the number of characters in my email message, the button functions, no errors.  I was looking in DocuSign documentation and it indicates that there is a character limit for the email message of 2000 characters.  Why can't I use this email message with 317 characters?  Anyone run into this?

Comment: It appears that the problem is that my email message has % symbol in it and DocuSign doesn't like that! Can now my question is - can I have a percent symbol in my email message in my custom button?

Comment: Try a backslash: \%
Or (for html email) use the html entity: &#37;

Comment: Thanks, Larry.  Tried backslash when I found the problem and that doesn't work.  I used the html entity you suggested and it just drops any text after that.  Any other ideas?